# Subscripting userInfo of NSError

Tags: swift, swift2

I have this piece of code in my WKWebView delegate method:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    var URL: NSURL? = webView.URL
    if URL == nil {
        let URLString: String = error.userInfo[NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]
        URL = NSURL(string: URLString)
    }
    print(URL)
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not compile. I get an error:

[image]

`Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'`

However if I change it like so, the code compiles just fine:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    var URL: NSURL? = webView.URL
    if URL == nil {
        if let urlString = error.userInfo[NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey] as? NSString {
            URL = NSURL(string: urlString as String)
        }
    }
    print(URL)
}
```

I don't like this solution because there's too much of unnecessary type-casting.

Why does the second solution work but the first one does not compile? Is there a better way how to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't  very helpful error message from the Swift compiler. What it means is that `URLString` really ought to be `AnyObject?`, but you're trying to force it to be a `String` – something that Swift won't allow unless you typecast it, as you do in your second example.

So, the second code works because you're pulling the key out of the dictionary and safely ensuring it's the right type before using it. If you're absolutely convinced you don't need that check (spoiler: you're probably wrong, sorry!), then you can write this:

```
let URLString = error.userInfo[NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey] as! String
```

That's only a couple of characters longer than your first solution. Note: clearly I think this is not a good idea – your second example (using `if/let`) is better.

Comment: Thanks. I've been perplexed by compiler error messages before, didn't learn my lesson yet it seems.

Comment: It's something Apple are aggressively working on; each Xcode release gets better. But yes, it's still not quite there yet!